# How I can create for my application one's own instance excel and use it?

Tags: c++, windows, com, process, ole

How I can create for my application one's own instance excel and use it ? Now I have com error when i call CreateInstance and there is a excel instance in process. I want to use for my application the global handler of excel instance and kill it when my application will be close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel allows multiple instances. The following code works with multiple instances (`XL`, `XL1`). And it works even if you previously start Excel manually. Would you show a code sample to clarify your question.

```
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE12\mso.dll"
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB"
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\excel.exe" \
  rename("DialogBox","ExcelDialogBox") rename("RGB","ExcelRGB") \
  exclude("IFont","IPicture")

#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  CoInitialize(NULL);
  try {
    Excel::_ApplicationPtr XL, XL1;

    HRESULT hr = XL.CreateInstance(L"Excel.Application");
    if(FAILED(hr)) {
      char msg[1024] = {0};
      sprintf(msg, "E: initializing first instance failed: %d", hr);
      throw std::runtime_error(msg);
    }

    Excel::_WorkbookPtr workbook = XL->Workbooks->Add(Excel::xlWorksheet); 
    Excel::_WorksheetPtr worksheet = XL->ActiveSheet;
    worksheet->SaveAs("c:\\test.xls");

    hr = XL1.CreateInstance(L"Excel.Application");
    if(FAILED(hr)) {
      char msg[1024] = {0};
      sprintf(msg, "E: initializing second instance failed: %d", hr);
      throw std::runtime_error(msg);
    }

    workbook->Close();
    XL->Quit();
    XL1->Quit();
  }
  catch(_com_error &ce)
  {
    std::cout<<"caught" << std::endl;
    // Handle the error
  }

  CoUninitialize();

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm working with OLE component of Excel. And I want to link my OLE object with right Excel process

Comment: Frankly, I do not understand the problem conditions and the environment. Are you using MSVC?